PHP8.3 + Smarty 5.0 and Explode/Implode
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Using implode is deprecated. Use join using the array first, separator second.

I'm getting the same deprecation warning with explode, telling me to use split.
Is this really the direction Smarty is going? I can't find any documentation on Smarty.net or Github.

Update 1: Adding some further detail using "implode()" as an example:
1. {$array|join:","}
2. {","|join:$array}
3. {$array|implode:","}
4. {","|implode:$array}

on PHP7.4, Smarty 3.x

Deprecated: join(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters
OK
Deprecated: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters
OK

on PHP8.3, Smarty 5.x

OK
Deprecated: Using join with the separator first is deprecated. Call join using the array first, separator second.
Deprecated: Using implode is deprecated. Use join using the array first, separator second.
Deprecated: Using implode is deprecated. Use join using the array first, separator second.


The recommendation here does not allow implode/explode without the deprecation notice.
https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/issues/813
$smarty->addExtension(new WildcardExtension());
class WildcardExtension extends \Smarty\Extension\Base {

    public function getModifierCallback(string $modifierName) {
        if (is_callable($modifierName)) {
            return $modifierName;
        }
        return null;
    }

}


What are recommendations for compatibility between both environments, without separate templates?

I think this thread from two years ago, with three upvotes and nine downvotes is what you are looking for. There’s several related merges, too.

If you haven't written any code on your own that triggers this error message, please post a bug report at the maintainer's repository

"...for compatibility between both environments..." - is there any reason to support PHP 7.4? It's outdated, and you've been advised to update your applications since years

That is a terrible design for Smarty5.
